# is docker-compose.yml not supported in AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In my root directory, I have my docker-compose.yml.

> $ ls

returns:

> build  cmd  docker-compose.yml  exp  go.mod  go.sum  LICENSE  media  pkg  README.md

In the same directory, I ran:

> $ eb init -p docker infogrid

> $ eb create infogridEnv

However, this gave me an error:

> Instance deployment: Both 'Dockerfile' and 'Dockerrun.aws.json' are missing in your source bundle. Include at least one of them. The deployment failed.

The fact that it does not even include docker-compose.yml as the missing file makes me think it does not support docker-compose. This is contradicting with the [main documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/docker.html) where it explicitly shows an example with docker-compose.yml.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you use "Amazon AMI" your enviroment should be the new "Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2"

only then you get the `docker-compose.yml` support

source https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/docker-multicontainer-migration.html